# Using regex with \b to match varying phrases in strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match some strings using regex. What I want to search is any string that talks about someone's children. Like for example: my son, my daughter, our daughters, etc

So I have written this in Python:

```
re.match(r'\b(my|our)\b \b(son|daughter|children|child|kid)s?', 'me and my son were')
```

But some how it doesn't match the `my son` in the test sentence. Returns `None`

I have tested this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/ChAy9e/1 and it works fine (5th line in test cases).

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the question is duplicate. The concept might be already answered earlier but I was not able to solve the problem myself because my lack of understanding of the difference. If I knew the difference already, this question, neither the original question would appear. The whole purpose is to help when you get stuck somewhere right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` matches the regex only at the start of the string; You need to use `findall` method

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b(my|our)\b \b(son|daughter|children|child|kid)s?', 'me and my son were')
[('my', 'son')]
```

> **match**
>       Try to apply the pattern at the **start** of the string, returning
>       a match object, or None if no match was found.

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks. I'll read `match` and `findall` documentation again.

Comment: @SureshS glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please kindly consider upvoting & accepting it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Vinny said, you need `re.findall`. However, if you want those phrases as one element, you'll want to modify your regex a bit. Try:

```
In [1]: re.findall(r'\b(?:my|our)\s+(?:son|daughter|kid)s?|children|child\b', 'me and my son were')
Out[1]: ['my son']
```

Remove capturing groups, so you capture single phrases at a time. I've also optimised your regex a bit, since you don't need to look for `childrens` and `childs` (that's incorrect grammar!).

**Details**

```
\b          # word boundary
(?:         # open non-capture group
    my          
    |           # 'or' operation
    our         
) 
\s+         # whitespace - one or more
(?:         # open non-capture group
    son        
    |
    daughter
    |
    kid
)
s?          # 's' optional           
|
children
|
child
\b          # word boundary
```